# FileNotFoundException in razor view ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I ran into a strange problem in my project.

This problem occurs when I want to return a specific razor view inside a method. But the point is that this problem only happens when I have used tag helpers like `asp-for`, otherwise there is no problem.

[Error Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOmPG.png)

Comment: There's a similar issue on github:https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/382 hope it could help

Comment: please make sure that you referenced all the necessary usings for your view, if you are not using view import, you should include these usings in all of your views
`@using EFCoreTraining2`
`@using EFCoreTraining2.Models`
`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you should update your Visual Studio's installation. You can't run the latest ASP.NET core apps with the older versions. [It's explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/versioning-sdk-msbuild-vs). Take a look at its `The Visual Studio / .NET Core SDK support matrix` to see what's the real problem.
- Also follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723132/298573

Comment: Thank you
I found the problem
There was only one wrong 'using'

Comment: Was that error message helpful to solve the problem? No! Will you see such a message if you run your app directly using the `dotnet watch run` command? No! How about using other IDE's which are not tied to the MSBuild? No!