# unable to build c# inside docker

Tags: c#, msbuild

Error

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
> Microsoft.Build.Logging.StructuredLogger.CompilerInvocationsReader.Read(String
> binLogFilePath)    at Broslyn.CSharpCompilationCapture.Build(String
> projectFileOrSolution, Dictionary`2 properties)    at Broslyn.CSharpCompilationCapture.Build(String projectFileOrSolution, String configuration, String platform, Dictionary`2 properties)    at
> Program.(String[] args)

adding `dotnet add package Microsoft.Build.Locator --version 1.6.10` will produce different error :)

to reproduce:

```bash
sudo docker build -f - --no-cache -t test . <<EOF
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.400
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch 13.0.3 https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.git /tmp/dep
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new console && dotnet add package Broslyn --version 1.2.0
#RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Build.Locator --version 1.6.10
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Build.Framework --version 17.5.0
COPY Program.cs .
CMD ["dotnet", "run", "/tmp/dep/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj"]
EOF
docker run test
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Broslyn;

var compilation = await CSharpCompilationCapture.Build(args[0])
    .Workspace
    .CurrentSolution
    .Projects.FirstOrDefault()!
    .GetCompilationAsync();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76251230/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-build-framework-version-15-1-0-0)

Comment: @JeffRSon unfortunately not

Comment: Looks like you need dotnet7 for Build Framework 17.5: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework/17.5.0